# How to make multiple jQuery animations on the same target run at the same time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

**place check the demo link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hep7fb1q/1)**

for some reason,**i have to separate two effect on two animation**,even it is on the same target,but i want the two effect play in the same time,how should i do?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".box").animate({width:10},"slow");
 $(".box").animate({left:100},"slow");
});
```

css

```
.box {
background-color: #f00;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
}
```

html

```
<div class="box" ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use margin-left instead if you want to keep its position

```
$(".box").animate({'width': '10px' , 'margin-left': '100px'},"slow");
```

see Demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hep7fb1q/2/)

Comment: Nice - Use `width:200px;` for `.box` css class, will effect more exact.

Comment: @Prog any width you will use it will make the same things for sure.. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @KentWood .animate() will make you wait until the first animate is finish

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef so,u mean there is noway to just play muti-animation on the same target in the same time?

Comment: @KentWood yes man there is noway to do that yet .. Until jquery solve that for us :)